# 正規表現を使ったファイルやフォルダパスのマッチング

Tags: 正規表現

以下に該当する文字列を正規表現でマッチングさせたいのですが、どう書けば良いでしょうか？

1. 拡張子txtとjpgのファイルパス
2. txtとjpgという名前のファイル及びフォルダを含むパス

実行環境は[RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/)です。
以下はtxtのみに絞ったテストケースです。

```
該当する
txt
txt/
/txt
.txt
foo.txt
txt/foo.txt
/foo.txt
/txt/foo.txt
/txt/foo/bar.baz
/bar/txt/foo.txt
/txt/txt/foo.bar


該当しない(1つ目の.txt には末尾にスペースあり)
.txt 
.txtfoo
.footxt
.footxtbar
.foo.txt.bar
.foo.txt*.bar
.foo.txt誤
.foo.txt誤.bar
.foo.誤txt
.txt foo
.foo.txt foo
foo.誤txt
txt.foo
/txt.foo
誤txt/foo.bar
bar/txt.foo
/bar/txt.foo
foo/bar/txt.baz
/foo/bar/txt.baz
/foo/bartxt/txt.baz
/foo/bar.txt/txt.baz
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^(((.*\/)?txt(\/.*)?)|(.*\.txt))$/gm`

http://www.regexr.com/3b66t

Comment: ありがとうございます(^_^)